# dynamically change icon based on the based on the text using angular 8 with font awesome

Tags: angular, font-awesome, angular8

I was trying to do dynamically change icon based on the value which is there in span

Here is my HTML actually in the version text there only two values will come

1. Active if it is active success icon should come
2. InActive if it is inactive Warning icon should come

I am not sure how to use ngclass here to get the value.

```
        <div class="pl-2">
            <div class="version-box">
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle text-warning ml-1"></i> 
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success ml-1"></i>
                <span class="version-label">{{selectedVersion.versionText}}</span></div>
        </div>
```

Please let me know how to bring that

Comment: Are you looking for dynamic class in <i> ? like this ? `<i class="fa fa-check-circle ml-1" [ngClass]="{selectedVersion.versionText == 'Active' ? 'text-warning': 'text-success'  }"></i>`

Comment: yes but the text-warning & text-success will be from font awesome icon right

Comment: if that's the case you can use *ngIf like `<span *ngIf="selectedVersion.versionText == 'Active' ">       <i class="fa fa-check-circle text-warning ml-1"></i> </span>`

Comment: I tried like this   
<div class="version-box"><span *ngIf="selectedVersion.versionText == 'active' "> <i
  class="fa fa-check-circle text-warning ml-1"></i>{{selectedVersion.versionText}}</span> </div> the value itself not coming now

Answer (score 0):

Since Font-Awesome uses classes: Just use the [ngClass] attribute:

```
<i class="fa fa-check-circle " [ngClass]="classToggle == true ? 'text-warning' : 'text-success'">
```

You can change any classes you like this way.

A [quick Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hedd9i)

Comment: thank you so much for the reply but I don't want color change i want only icon has to change and there is no action needed like toggle class based on the value the icon has to change

Comment: so do [ngClass]="classToggle==true ? 'fa-check-circle' : 'fa-exclamation-triangle'" or whatever icon you need. If you look at your code, the Icon is just a class

Comment: @Mahadevan The concept is the same though. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hedd9i Just change your FA class based on some attribute (perhaps a property on the item).